# g++ and Clang regarding array size

Tags: c++

I've noticed that this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    int k;
    cin >> k;
    int n[k];
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        n[i] = i;

    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        cout << n[i] << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

compiles just fine. Could anyone clarify on this, because as far as I'm aware, static arrays must have a constant as their size.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[clang](http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#vla) and [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html) support [variable length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) as an extension in C++ even though it is a C99 feature. If you compile with the `-pedantic` flag they will both provide a warning for example this is what `clang` says:

```
warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'n' [-Wvla]
 int n[k];
        ^
```

You can turn it into an error using the `-pedantic-errors` flag.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to enable the -pedantic by default, I've only recently switched to clang?

Comment: It is going to depend on what interface you are using. I am usually using a command line so I would have to figure it out myself.

Comment: @Frows Generally there's no way to set implicit default flags. Clang wants all flags to be supplied every time explicitly, though you can automate *that* part. Either you automate your build process (using Makefiles, an IDE, or another build tool) and add the flag *there*, or you create an alias in the shell, or you pass it every time. Just make a habit of adding `-Wall` to all compiler invocations :-)

Comment: I'm using NetBeans 7.4, works fine with terminal but I'm looking into making it enabled by default

Comment: @Frows what delnan said pretty much sums it up but NetBeans probably has a way to set that up.

Comment: @Frows NetBeans presumable has some settings to add flags to the compiler invocation (most likely in some sort of project settings dialog), but since I never used it, you'll have to search on your own.